# Why is callvirt used to call a method on a readonly field of generic type

Tags: c#, cil, intermediate-language

Consider the following:

```
interface ISomething
{
    void Call(string arg);
}

sealed class A : ISomething
{
    public void Call(string arg) => Console.WriteLine($"A, {arg}");
}

sealed class Caller<T> where T : ISomething
{
    private readonly T _something;
    public Caller(T something) => _something = something;
    public void Call() => _something.Call("test");
}

new Caller<A>(new A()).Call();
```

Both the call to Caller<A>.Call, as well as its nested tcall to A.Call are lodged through the callvirt instruction.

But why? Both types are exactly known. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, shouldn't it be possible do use call rather than callvirt here?

If so - why is this not done? Is that merely an optimisation not done by the compiler, or is there any specific reason behind this?

Comment: The nested call cannot be changed to non-virt. The `Caller` class is not aware of what the exact type of `T` is, and the IL has to be generated at compile time for all possible `T`. The top level call can be devirtualized though. I don't know why this optimization is not there. It is possible that JIT does that, but still, it is already possible at IL level. Also with non-virt call, inlining is possible, which then allows devirtualization of the nested call as well. But C# does not inline stuff at IL level as well, for some reason most optimizations are moved to JIT.

Comment: I don't follow the first part. Caller<A> should be aware of the exact type through the generic type argument - which in this case happens to be the sealed type A right? I'd agree that the type Caller<A> has to be explicitly created at compile time - but why could this optimisation not be done at that point?

Comment: "the type Caller<A> has to be explicitly created at compile time" - no, .NET's generics are not C++ templates. The Constructed closed generic type doesn't exist until runtime.

Comment: Most of optimization is done by the jit, not the il compiler.

Comment: @Bogey `Caller<A>` is not created at compile time, only `Caller<T>` is. C# generics are not the same as C++ templates. Furthermore C# compiler does not inline stuff as far as I know (but JIT does!). And so it cannot do this optimization at IL level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing two things.

The first is that `callvirt` does a null-check on the receiver, whereas `call` does not. This means that using `callvirt` on a `null` receiver will raise a `NullReferenceException`, whereas `call` will happily call the method and pass `null` as the first parameter, meaning that the method will get a `this` parameter which is `null`.

Sound surprising? It is. IIRC in very early .NET versions `call` *was* used in the way you suggest, and people got very confused about how `this` could be `null` inside a method. The compiler switched to `callvirt` to force the runtime to do a null-check upfront.

There are only a handful of places where the compiler will emit a `call`:

1. Static methods.
2. Non-virtual struct methods.
3. Calling a base method or base constructor (where we know the receiver is not `null`, and we also explicitly do not want to make a virtual call).
4. Where the compiler is certain that the receiver is not null, e.g. `foo?.Method()` where `Method` is non-virtual.

That last point in particular means that making a method `virtual` is a binary-breaking change.

Just for fun, see [this check for `this == null`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,570) in `String.Equals`.

---

The second thing is that `_something.Call("test");` is not a virtual call, it's a *constrained* virtual call. There's a [`constrained` opcode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained?view=net-6.0) which appears before it.

Constrained virtual calls were introduced with generics. The problem is that method calls on classes and on structs are a bit different:

1. For classes, you load the class reference (e.g. with `ldloc`), then use `call` / `callvirt` .
2. For structs, you load the *address* of the struct (e.g. with `ldloc.a`), then use `call`.
3. To call an interface method on a struct, or a method defined on `object`, you need to load the struct value (e.g. with `ldloc`), box it, then use `call` / `callvirt`.

If a generic type is unconstrained (i.e. it could be a class or a struct), the compiler doesn't know what to do: should it use `ldloc` or `ldloc.a`? Should it box or not? `call` or `callvirt`?

Constrained virtual calls move this responsibility to the runtime. To quote the doc above:

> When a `callvirt` `method` instruction has been prefixed by `constrained` `thisType`, the instruction is executed as follows:
>
> - If `thisType` is a reference type (as opposed to a value type) then `ptr` is dereferenced and passed as the 'this' pointer to the `callvirt` of `method`.
> - If `thisType` is a value type and `thisType` implements `method` then `ptr` is passed unmodified as the 'this' pointer to a `call` `method` instruction, for the implementation of `method` by `thisType`.
> - If `thisType` is a value type and `thisType` does not implement `method` then `ptr` is dereferenced, boxed, and passed as the 'this' pointer to the `callvirt` `method` instruction.
>
> This last case can occur only when `method` was defined on `System.Object`, `System.ValueType`, or `System.Enum` and not overridden by `thisType`. In this case, the boxing causes a copy of the original object to be made. However, because none of the methods of `System.Object`, `System.ValueType`, and `System.Enum` modify the state of the object, this fact cannot be detected.

Comment: Clearly the top level call to `.Call()` is not on `null`. And it can be devirtualized. There's just no way to call a different method in OP's setup.

Comment: @freakish The compiler simply doesn't optimize this case. Yes this very specific case is clear, but it's not particularly common in practice. It's more common to construct a type and store the result in a variable, and then call a method on the variable, and suddenly tracking whether the variable can become null in the meantime becomes harder. Also, Microsoft try to put these sorts of optimizations, such as devirtualisation, into the runtime rather than the compiler, so all CLR languages benefit. And indeed, in this case the runtime inlines the whole call

Comment: Yes, tracking is harder, but as you said: JIT already does that (or so they say). I don't see a benefit of moving that optimization to JIT and thus increasing JIT compilation time. It's a weird decision to move all optimizations to JIT to be honest. Especially optimizations that are platform independent.

Comment: It means that they don't need to implement the same optimizations 3 times for C#, VB.NET, and F#, and 3rd-party languages also benefit. The JIT also has a lot more knowledge than the compiler: it knows what concrete types are in use at runtime, which means it can devirtualise/inline significantly more than the compiler would be able to

Comment: ECMA-335 Section III.2.1 might be a better place to link https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_5th_edition_december_2010.pdf

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah, but I can't link to an exact page there, and the MSDN docs are copied straight from the relevant sections in ECMA-335 (albeit from an old edition, but I don't think the docs on `callvirt` have changed)

Comment: Highly interesting, thanks @canton7. Sounds like IF we had a way to constraint T to be a sealed class, and ensured non-nullability, the compiler should be able to emit call instead of callvirt? (Purely theoretical due to the lack of any sealed constraint)

Comment: @Bogey I guess. I'm not sure whether it would bother: compiler-driven devirtualisation isn't really a big win (it's done for obviously correct cases like `?.`). The wins come when the runtime manages to do it

Comment: @Bogey No, the compiler does not make any optimization for nullability. And even if you were *not* using generics, it does not optimize for sealed classes

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't even bother in [this case](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLAChUDcCGAnABAE1wF5cA7AUwHdcARc7Mdc/ACgEoBuVfAfgDoAYgHsh7LmhQwAzLni4AQpgDO5VAG9UuLVum50YbMACumCLIAsuYaLa41uAL7bUD1Kl0rTzWXFr1G3iAKyqooGijasjJCTNgM+OQWViLsdo4uQA).

Comment: Fair - let's rather phrase this as, it "could" in theory legitimately optimise these cases then (even if it doesn't actually bother to do so)

Comment: @Bogey - if you're constraining the type down to a single sealed type, why are you using generics?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That was more out of academic curiosity (but you could probably run into scenarios like that in a typical DI setup, where you tend to inject a small subset - if not even just one - implementation of some interface into anything that isn't a unit test)